# Do solar flares affect the software when the hardware is turned off?

Tags: electromagnetism, flipflop, hardware

Do solar flares affect the software when the device is turned off? Like for example, would the windows os got corrupted even when the hard drive is off?

Comment: Do solar flares affect the software when the hardware is turned on?

Comment: also include usb, cd, etc into account.

Comment: This is interesting. Apparently a solar flare would not be enough to damage electronics, but a coronal mass ejection would. I would think that a HDD could possibly be damaged by a CME. But it is more likely to be effected by the fluctuations on the power grid. http://science.howstuffworks.com/solar-flare-electronics2.htm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The computers and other electronics hardware, as well as the information medias, actually fails all the time and one part of these failures is caused by the high energy cosmic particles. Fortunately, these failures are not so big part of all failures.

If I have to estimate the risk, I would say that the magnetic media is less prone to such a failures than the electronic mediam where the information is stored as a electric charges - (EPROM and Flash memories are one of these)

BTW, DRAM memory stores the information as a charge and this way is highly vulnerable for radiation rays - that is why the software fails mainly when the computer runs, when the information is placed in the DRAM memory.

Also, higher information density of the media often means higher vulnerability.

So, the answer - Yes it is possible, but not very likely. And even if happens sometimes, the one will never distinct these cases from the more probable failures because of electronic parts defects, overheating, limited life elements, planned obsolescence, power surges, etc, etc.

Comment: effect on softwares i.e, bits n bytes? , without any failure to hardware. Is missing in your answer.

Comment: @WaqarAhmad Well, the failure reasons are very similar for the software and hardware failures, as long as the software failure usually means hardware failure (changed information on the media, while it should not to be changed).

Comment: @WaqarAhmad you never asked in your question for corruption of data without hardware damage. In fact, you tagged this question as "hardware." You should edit your question if that is what you wanted.

Comment: @trav1s i think thats ok so for. I got the clues from the answers given. Ofcourse the data is within the hardware:)

Answer (score 1):

Not on earth's surface.
In space, solar flares and cosmic rays can flip bits in digital circuits, including any magnetic storage device.

Comment: Solar flares and cosmic rays are *attenuated* by the atmosphere and the magnetosphere, not blocked. This is therefore not technically correct.